# Bootstrap grid not working inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code works correctly:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Edit" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EditCidade" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EditEmpresa" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EditFuncionario" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The three textboxs are in the same row, taking 33% of the space.
But then I tried to put the modal inside an IFrame and the three textboxs are taking the whole line again, the "col-sm-4" doesn't seems to have any effect.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Edit" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <iframe runat="server" id="editIFrame" style="width: 100%; height: 270px" frameborder="0" src="EditField"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the IFrame itself:

```
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
       <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditCidade" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditEmpresa" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditFuncionario" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I suspect the < form> has something to do with it, but I can't take it off because I'm using ASP...
Or it's the width/height of the IFrame... Anyway, I don't know how to solve it and I need help.

Comment: PS: I've tried using col-sm, col-md, col-lg, col-xs, none of these works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What iframe tag does it is inserting a whole new document inside your page. I think you need to link bootstrap again inside your iframe content. Also Bootstrap grid system requires 'container' or 'container-fluid' class as a parent for rows:

```
<body>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
                    <!--added container class -->
       <div class="modal-body container" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditCidade" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditEmpresa" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditFuncionario" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I added 'container' class, try it now @Lucas

Comment: Worked with container class and col-xs. Solved, thank you

Comment: didn't wotk. I linked all css needed, but it seem to not keep the float and width rules because didn't match the media query of device/screen width

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this is to create this class:

```
.iframe-container {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .iframe-container iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Then have your iFrame use it, like:

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")' class="iframe-container" width="100%" height="500" frameBorder="0" name="Forgot_Iframe"> 
  </iframe>
```

This will make sure bootstrap grid system works on your modal iFrame.
 Solution taken from: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/